# difference between SDO and JDO in java

Tags: java, jdo, sdo

what is the difference between JDO (JSR 243) and SDO (JSR 235) in Java; what set of open source providers are available for these java specifications

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Data_Objects http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Data_Objects

Comment: DataNucleus implements the full range of JDO specifications and is used by many companies. I don't know of any company that uses SDO to any degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-sdo/):

> [...] JDO looks at the persistence
>   issue only [...] whereas SDO is more general and represents data that can flow
>   between any J2EE tier, such as between a presentation and business
>   tier.

[EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/sdo.php) is one SDO provider, [Apache's DB project](http://db.apache.org/jdo/) is one JDO implementation.

Comment: Can i achieve all the functionality using SDO which JDO can accomplish ?

Comment: Correction : Apache JDO project includes the API and TCK for JDO. It does not have an implementation. DataNucleus is the "Reference Implementation" for JDO 2, 2.1, 2.2 and 3.0

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunate version numbering, though; Version 3.0 implements 3.1. 2.1 support 3.0. 1.0 supports 2.2. *sigh*

Comment: @Dave if it just implemented JDO then i'd agree totally ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For an excerpt you can read the "Request" part on the appropriate JSR pages for [JDO](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=243#2) and [SDO](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=235#2).

In practice and for quick starters: JDO is the father of JPA.

- JPA is actually used and usable (this is not for granted in the Java EE world), Hibernate and EclipseLink are two well known opensource implmenetations of JPA.
- SDO: I have neither seen it in any project I've been, nor have I heard about it so far. Reading the Blurb on the JCP Page made me feel that this is one of those overgeneralized and clumsy Java EE standards not designed for real life.

Feel free to ignore SDO for now while digging into JPA a bit.